# FMDB Crash : [FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:]

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, fmdb

I'm using FMDB `FMDatabaseQueue` for read/write into multi-threaded app database. here is my code that looks like,

In background thread:

```
[queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {

        for (NSDictionary *dic in ary) {

           //long process  
           //  .
           //  .

            bol = [db executeUpdate:@"insert query"];
        } 
    }];
```

In UI thread:

```
double Price1=[self getPrice];
double Price2=[self getPrice];

-(double )getPrice{

    __block double price=0.0;

    [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

        FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:querySQL];
        if([rs next])
            price=[rs doubleForColumnIndex:1];
    }];


    return price;
}
```

queue is a singleton `FMDatabaseQueue` object.my multi-threaded app crashed with reason:

```
FMDatabase.m line 776 -[FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:]
FMDatabase.m line 896 -[FMDatabase executeQuery:]
```

Any idea why this crash happened. Any solution?

Comment: About the func getPrice. Since you fire a query in a queue, I think getPrice could return a price earlier than the query is finished.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @ Allen    

return [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
     return price;
    }];

may i return like this?